# How to merge different MySQL queries with set values into single query in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, join

I want to merge four different SQL queries into single query in order to reduce usage of SQL connections

This is my code:

```
        long WTPty = 0L; // holds some value from other part of program
        long NTPty = 0L; // holds some value from other part of program
        long ETPty = 0L; // holds some value from other part of program
        long STPty = 0L; // holds some value from other part of program

            Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
//query 1    
    String w_tblpty="update tbl_priority SET total='"+WTPty+"' where priority= 'west'";
    stmt.executeUpdate(w_tblpty);
//query 2     
    String n_tblpty="update tbl_priority SET total='"+NTPty+"' where priority= 'north'";
    stmt.executeUpdate(n_tblpty);
//query 3     
    String s_tblpty="update tbl_priority SET total='"+STPty+"' where priority= 'south'";
    stmt.executeUpdate(s_tblpty);
//query 4     
    String e_tblpty="update tbl_priority SET total='"+ETPty+"' where priority= 'east'";
    stmt.executeUpdate(e_tblpty);
```

My objective is to reduce SQL connection usage and optimize the code. Is it possible to merge the above four queries into just single one?

Comment: Hi, Any piece of code is highly appreciated & Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Firstly, start using parameterized SQL with prepared statements instead of putting values directly in the SQL. Then use `addBatch`...

Comment: `UPDATE` statements are not *queries*. A "query" is defined in the English language as "a question or a request for information". In SQL context, that means a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jon Skeet said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210475/how-to-merge-different-mysql-queries-with-set-values-into-single-query-in-java#comment69619666_41210475), use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), [`addBatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch--), and [`executeBatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch--). Also, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
String sql = "UPDATE tbl_priority SET total = ? where priority = ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setLong  (1, WTPty);
    stmt.setString(2, "west");
    stmt.addBatch();

    stmt.setLong  (1, NTPty);
    stmt.setString(2, "north");
    stmt.addBatch();

    stmt.setLong  (1, STPty);
    stmt.setString(2, "south");
    stmt.addBatch();

    stmt.setLong  (1, ETPty);
    stmt.setString(2, "east");
    stmt.addBatch();

    stmt.executeBatch();
}
```

Comment: More secure version :p

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addBatch` method on the Statement object :

```
    long WTPty = 0L; // holds some value from other part of program
    long NTPty = 0L; // holds some value from other part of program
    long ETPty = 0L; // holds some value from other part of program
    long STPty = 0L; // holds some value from other part of program

    Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
    //query 1    
    String w_tblpty="update tbl_priority SET total='"+WTPty+"' where priority= 'west'";
    //query 2     
    String n_tblpty="update tbl_priority SET total='"+NTPty+"' where priority= 'north'";
    //query 3     
    String s_tblpty="update tbl_priority SET total='"+STPty+"' where priority= 'south'";
    //query 4     
    String e_tblpty="update tbl_priority SET total='"+ETPty+"' where priority= 'east'";
    stmt.addBatch(w_tblpty);
    stmt.addBatch(n_tblpty);
    stmt.addBatch(s_tblpty);
    stmt.addBatch(e_tblpty);
    stmt.executeBatch();
```

Comment: That looks nice. I'll try it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome ! If that works, do not forget to validate answer ;)